# .htaccess / redirecting to https://www.example.com and virtual folder access

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I have a domain *example.com*. I want users to be redirected to `https://www.example.com` whenever one of the following is typed:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `https://example.com`

I also need to redirect people accessing `/asdf` (or `/asdf/`) to `/index.php?folder=asdf`.

I found some examples of code doing the first part, but there was always a debate about their effectiveness.

---

Edit: (need some more help! :))

Comment: Hmm - I think I should have posted my addon query here... :) [its below in response to Gumbo]

Answer (score 3):

Try these [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html) rules:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond $1 !=index.php
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?folder=$1 [L]
```

But I recommend you to just allow one URL notation, the one with or without the trailing slash.

Comment: Hi there Gumbo - The first part of it works quite well, but for the second part, I need some more help. I want all users accessing "www.example.com" to access a "index.html" file, but anyone accessing example.com/abcde/ to be redirected to example.com/subfolder=abcde . One more complication is that I have a special (but "real") folder at: www.example.com/qwerty/ . Any links within those should not be altered.

Thanks! Your earlier example was very helpful!

Comment: Whoops - minor typo: I meant to say "anyone accessing example.com/abcde/ to be redirected to example.com/other.php?subfolder=abcde"